# Visual Studio 2010 crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium with SP1, together with Team Explorer 2008, installed in Windows 7 x64.
Recently my Visual Studio 2010 keep crashing every 3-5 mins while doing coding, the message is like "Visual studio encountered problem", and then "Visual Studio is restarting".

I've uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium, still having the same problem, crashing every 3-5 mins while doing coding.  I even reinstall Team Explorer 2010, but still did not solve the problem.

Anyway to find out what is the cause of the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What say the event logs?

Comment: This is the detail in event viewer:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x2464
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd2815fa5ec164
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: b39be01b-940a-11e1-9cee-402cf4623a34